# Angular access to headers from activatedRoute (or similar?)

Tags: angular, routes, http-headers, angular-activatedroute

I tired looking around but couldn't find any solution.

From Angular (using v7), how can I retrieve the request HEADERS from an activatedRoute?

My use case is that an authentication provider calls my Angular page and provides the uuid of the user activated via the `referrer request header`, which I need to retrieve.

I've used the `activatedRoute` for *query parameters*, but it doesn't seem to provide a way to query **headers**.
I was thinking also to use the `Routes`, but it doesn't seem possible to access the headers over there too.

Thanks!

Comment: headers should come from an API request, what do you mean by `ActivatedRoute` headers?

Comment: Because headers where sent to HTTP server that serving your app's files, not to your application running in browser. You need to expose them to query params somehow to get access from angular app.